# difficulty targeting only visible panels using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a combination of Jquery and Bootstrap. I'm trying to target only visible panels.  If I get rid of the first line, of code, the function work, but targets all panels in my HTML, which I don't want.  If I keep the first line of code, the function doesn't carry through at all.

```
$(".panel:visible").each(function(){

$("#1star").on("click", function() {
$(".5star").show();
$(".4star").show();
$(".3star").show();
$(".2star").show();
$(".1star").show();
});
```

And yes, I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, but I'm confined to html, css, and jQuery.

:::edit:: html requested.

```
div class="panel panel-default pa 5star">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Pa hotel 5 star
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default pa 4star">
      <div class="panel-body">
      pa hotel 4 star
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default pa 3star">
      <div class="panel-body">
      pa hotel 3 star
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default pa 2star">
      <div class="panel-body">
      pa hotel 2 star
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default pa 1star">
      <div class="panel-body">
      pa hotel 1 star
      </div>
    </div>
```

::edit 2:::
the reason all the panels are hidden is because 1.They are by default and two this other piece of Jq

```
if (acceptNJ[stateSearch.toLowerCase()]) {
$(".nj").fadeIn(2000);
$(".pa").hide();
$(".ny").hide();
```

Comment: Please show HTML as well.

Comment: If that loop is likely to run more than once, you will end up with multiple event handlers

Answer (score 0):

We're missing some of your HTML to get the full picture.  It appears though you have a filter capability and you want to display the panels at or above the minimum star value for the selected state.

Here is a rough example:  https://jsfiddle.net/rfh62c45/

```
   // hide all panels 
   $('.panel').hide();

   var visibleState = $('#state :selected').text();
   var iStar = $('#star :selected').text();

   while (iStar <= 5) {
       $('.' + visibleState + '.' + iStar + 'star').fadeIn(2000); 
       iStar++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get visibility state with

```
$(".4star").is(":visible")
```

with jquery. This returns true or false. 
**true =  visible ,
false = hidden**

Hope this helps.